# Delete function from psql console

Tags: postgresql, function, sql-delete

I try to find how to delete function from database
But nothing
I know how to create it

```
create or replace function getMyLocationsCount(idFirst int, idSecond int)
    returns int
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    location_count integer;
begin
    select count(*)
    into location_count
    from locations
    where id between idFirst and idSecond;
    return location_count;
end;
$$;

select getMyLocationsCount(1,3);
```

but how to delete it?

Comment: `drop function getmylocationscount(int, int);`?

Comment: Thanks!!! This is decision